# Elasticsearch data integrity issue with MariaDB

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, mariadb, logstash, elastic-stack

I have set up 2 identical ELK servers to sync MariaDB (restored from dump sql so it's inactive table, no active insert activity) table in my test environment.

This MariaDB table consist of 15,359,086 rows.

However I noticed count mismatch when data is synced to Elasticsearch using Logstash.

From 1st ELK server, I got this amount using count API

```
{
    "count": 15936359,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    }
}
```

and from 2nd ELK server

```
{
    "count": 14934148,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    }
}
```

What causes this discrepancies when syncing? None of the ELK returned correct value from the source and both stacks give different count even the setup is identical

I'm using this count API from Postman

```
GET http://localhost:9200/index/_count
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "type" : "column in DB" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the count API call you executed?

Comment: Update question with count API

Answer (score 2):

Too long for comment:

When it comes to calculate the number of columns in an InnoDB table, the values ​​are often an estimate or a snapshot but not the accurate number of rows.

For an example, if these values were obtained from `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table_name'` you might get incorrect number of rows.

To make sure that filling data by a dump file succeeded, a possible solution would be to use explain on every table which was created and filled by executing the dump file:

`EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(indexed_colum) FROM your_table`.

In case you prefer `SELECT COUNT(*) from your_table` and the table doesn't use any index, consider to go out for coffee before waiting for result.

Check the result  and compare it if it matches the number on the other server instance.

Comment: thanks for explaining that +1. Do you know why two instances of ES have different numbers as OP has shown in his post?